# Why regulations on refrigerant and not on efforts in preparing standard for leak proof refrigeration system?

Tags: thermodynamics, manufacturing-engineering, environmental-engineering, refrigeration

Refrigerants from CFC series are banned due to environmental concerns,but why not focus on preparing a standard for registration system which minimize or eliminate leakage?
It must be difficult to manufacture such system.but why?

Comment: What happens when someone decides to throw their machines away?

Comment: Because the *only* reason there are refrigerant regs is to protect the patent holding refrigerant mfgs. The refrigerants have been phased out as their patent protection expired, forcing the adoption of new, patented refrigerants and preventing a flood of cheap foreign gas.

Comment: opinion based questions are off topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Because you can control refrigerant at the source

If a refrigerant can't be manufactured, it will go away.  As prices go up, keeping systems from leaking becomes more important.  No one can control procedures in the field.  Experience says that any system that can leak will leak.

The bans of CFC's and now HCFC's have been extremely effective at what they were designed to do.  That said, [crooks in China appear to be making more R-11, contrary to the ban.](https://research.noaa.gov/article/ArtMID/587/ArticleID/2713/Emissions-of-a-banned-ozone-depleting-gas-are-back-on-the-decline)